# Не срабатывает условие в цикле For на Python

Tags: python, циклы, for

Есть задача - удалить из списка все элементы длинна которых меньше 7.

По какой-то причине удаляются все элементы кроме одного.

```
a = ['Oneoneone', 'Two', 'Threethree', 'Four', 'Fivefive', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eighteight', 'Nine', 'Tententen']
for elem in a:
   if len(elem) < 7:
      a.remove(elem)
print(a)
```

Результат

```
['Oneoneone', 'Threethree', 'Fivefive', 'Seven', 'Eighteight', 'Tententen']
```

Seven - тоже должно быть удалено.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело?